# Can I store my sharedpreference to my cache directory in Android app?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have some key-value pairs to store in cache. I known sharedpreference is a good and simple method to implement it. But it seems the sharedpreference store file in data directory rath than in cache directory.

How could I do it in best practice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using DataStore - Protocol Buffers.

> DataStore is a new and improved data storage solution aimed at
> replacing SharedPreferences. Built on Kotlin coroutines and Flow,
> DataStore provides two different implementations: Proto DataStore,
> that lets you store typed objects (backed by protocol buffers) and
> Preferences DataStore, that stores key-value pairs. Data is stored
> asynchronously, consistently, and transactionally, overcoming some of
> the drawbacks of SharedPreferences.
>
> What are protocol buffers?
> Protocol buffers are Google's language-neutral, platform-neutral, extensible mechanism for serializing structured data – think XML, but smaller, faster, and simpler. You define how you want your data to be structured once, then you can use special generated source code to easily write and read your structured data to and from a variety of data streams and using a variety of languages.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers)

[Example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore/#0)

Answer (score 0):

**To your specific question:**

The official DatStore guide uses the `cacheDir` but this might reset your preferences when you install the app freshly, start the app, kill the app and start the app again (was reproducable on my side).

Thus, it's recommended to store it in the `filesDir` as it's also done in `androidx.datastore.DataStoreFile.kt`:

```
public fun Context.dataStoreFile(fileName: String): File =
    File(applicationContext.filesDir, "datastore/$fileName")
```

---

**In general: Use DataStore not SharedPreferences**

If you just need a very simple way to store key-value pairs without type safety, you can just use DataStore Preferences (instead of deprecated SharePreferences):

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-datastore

Alternatively, you can you can use Protobuf DataStore which comes with type safety, but you have the additional overhead of defining the proto messages (settings schema) and you may also need to write migration code and versionize the messages at some point in the future:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#proto-datastore